# написание скрипта в скрипте JS

Tags: javascript, html

имеется такой код:

```
<script>
var newWin = window.open("about:blank", "hello", "width=200,height=200");
var html = "<html><body><h1>123</h1></body><script>window.print()</script></html>";
newWin.document.write(html);
</script>
```

но он интерпретируется неправильно, `</script>` находящийся в строке html расценивается браузером как закрывающий тэг первой строки, т.е. последний закрывающий script остается без пары, а на странице появляется `'; newWin.document.write(html);`

задача: открытие нового окна и вызов диалога печати. для меня очень странно что браузер часть значения строки воспринимает как html который необходимо интерпретировать.

может есть более лаконичные способы решения моей задачи?

Comment: куча вариантов. самое простое - напишите так

`var html = "<html><body><h1>123</h1></body><"+"script>window.print()</"+"script></html>";`

Comment: Так будет еще проще: `var html = "<html><body><h1>123</h1></body><script>window.print()<\/script></html>";`

Comment: Пробовали добавить нормальный doctype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По правилам парсинга сначала находится завершающий тег `</script>`, и только потом парсится содержимое скрипта. Поэтому для написания в строке внутри скрипта `</script>` надо использовать конкатенацию строк или фиктивное экранирование.

```html
<script>
  document.write("<script>document.write(1)</" + "script>");
</script>

<script>
  document.write("<script>document.write(2)<\/script>");
</script>
```